# Angular 2 dropdown directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I can find lots of Q&As on dropdown components that have the content dynamically created, something like this:
`<dropdown (items)="some.items" [click]="doSomething($event)" etc... />`

I need a more generic and reusable directive that would allow the dropdown to contain any logic / template. Something like:

```
<dropdown>
   <button class="dropdown-toggle">Toggle Dropdown!</button>
   <something class="dropdown-content">This is the dropdown content...</button>
</dropdown>
```

The directive needs to provide the logic to handle element hide / show toggle and document click (not on the element) to hide the dropdown. What the best way to tackle this? All the Angular 2 stuff I have done is component this their own views...

Comment: what's wrong with the `template` instruction of the `@component` declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **Content Projection** (Angular 1 Transclusion) for that purpose:

```
<dropdown>
   <h1>This is a Content Projection!</h1>
</dropdown>
```

And in the template of the DropdownComponent:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <ng-content></ng-content>

    <p>Beside the projected content, dropdown can have its own content..</p>
</div>
```

The result will be the following:

```
<h1>This is a Content Projection!</h1>
<p>Beside the projected content, dropdown can have its own content..</p>
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! 
It's explained here very well: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content